what is equivalent OracleType.RowId in Oracle.ManagedDataAccessClient?
I'm trying convert old code C# :
OracleType.RowId

but I can't find any type for this code. what exactly is type file in OracleDbType?

Looks like this does not exist. You need to convert the ROWID into string. Function ROWIDTOCHAR and CHARTOROWID may help you.
